How to get lp pair key from mint address of a raydium token?
I want to get a LP key pair(WSOL-TOKEN). For example in $WIF, the mint addres is EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm, but I want to get EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx.
I'm using solanaweb3 nodejs library.
https://solscan.io/token/EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm
I need to get the Raydium lp key:

EDIT: I figured it out by using https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api
The quote api returns you the amm key.

I believe jupiter api works well. Alternatively i snatched some code from raydium sdk v2:

import axios from 'axios';
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';

const tokenMint = "AFivsHqtajxcbQmyuZ7TQymx1ypSs6S74dLEY4BGRxXf";

function normalizeRaydiumBetaPoolInfoResponse(response) {

  if (!response || typeof response !== 'object') {
    return [];
  }

  const items = Array.isArray(response) 
    ? response 
    : (Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data : []);

  return items.filter(p => 
    p && p.price && p.mintAmountA && p.mintAmountB &&
    p.mintA && p.mintB
  );
}

async function fetchPoolInfo( tokenMint ) {

  const mint1 = tokenMint;
  const mint2 = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112";
  const poolType = "standard";
  const poolSortField = "default";
  const sortType = "desc";
  const pageSize = 100;
  const page = 1;

  const url = `https://api-v3.raydium.io/pools/info/mint?mint1=${mint1}&mint2=${mint2}&poolType=${poolType}&poolSortField=${poolSortField}&sortType=${sortType}&pageSize=${pageSize}&page=${page}`;

  try {

    const response = await axios.get(url);

    return response.data.data.data;

  } catch (error) {

    console.error("Error fetching pool info:", error);
  }
}

const tokenPool = normalizeRaydiumBetaPoolInfoResponse(
  await fetchPoolInfo( tokenMint )
).find(p => 
  p.mintA.address === tokenMint || p.mintB.address === tokenMint
);

const rayPool = new PublicKey( tokenPool.id );


Your question is missing an important part that you want to fetch LP id by api call or you wanna just find out where to find LP id.
if you wanna check what is the LP id of a mint adress, i suggest you to go over geckoterminal or dexscreener and check pair .
if you wanna make an api call to fetch LP id by mint adress then you should find an api that can make a call for such info.

I want to get it programmatically. As far as I know, no API has a direct method that gets this.

You can get top pools for a token by sending request to that api and is free:
https://api.geckoterminal.com/api/v2/networks/solana/tokens/{token_adress}/pools
if you make an api call to that api you can get from the response.
There are other ways to achieve that info but I think that one is most simplest

You can also obtain LP mint from liquidty add transaction signature ...
